# How to create contact automatically?

Tags: android, contacts

Im building a program that needs to add a contact to the contact list automatically at the beginning of a program. How would i go about doing this? And is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: add a contact? like in the contact list? care to explain better what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Here's how you add Abraham Lincoln when your app starts:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        // Add Abraham Lincoln to contacts and make him a favorite.
        values.put(People.NAME, "Abraham Lincoln");
        // 1 = the new contact is added to favorites
        // 0 = the new contact is not added to favorites
        values.put(People.STARRED, 1);

        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(People.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
}
```

Check out Content Providers: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: read the link I posted. its all there. don't forget to mark this as an answer, it increases our rep.

Comment: Yeah i know but i guess because im low level it takes 9 minutes before i can accept it. I just tried.

Comment: values.put(People.Phones.NUMBER, "1233214567");

Comment: Thanks man! One problem in my eclipse. The People.NAME is showing up with a black line going through it??

Comment: yeah the Contacts.People class is deprecated, which means it will still work but may be removed from future versions. check this out instead: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.html

Comment: It's working fine but how to create a contact using ContactContracts api Becoz android.provider.Contacts methods are not applicable for api level above 4